# Hibernate 6 for Spring Boot 6.2 do not work with unaccent

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

When trying to switch from Hibernate 5 to Hibernate 6, the search with unaccent do not work cause of the error :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Operand of 'like' is of type 'java.lang.Object' which is not a string (it is not an instance of 'java.lang.String' or 'char[]')

Hibernate 6 detect the result of unaccent as a Object and not a String, meaning that we can not do LIKE on it...

The code :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT myentity FROM MyEntity myentity WHERE unaccent(LOWER(myentity.name)) like CONCAT('%', :name, '%')")
List<MyEntity> searchByName(String search);
```

I tryed to remove CONCAT or LOWER and the problem really come from unaccent

```
@Query(value = "SELECT myentity FROM MyEntity myentity WHERE unaccent(myentity.name) like :search")
List<MyEntity> searchByName(String search);
```

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
BrandonFL

Comment: Have you tried to use native query instead of jpql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unaccent` PSQL is not known to return a String thus SQM returns an error because LIKE works only with Strings

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#query-sqm
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-functions-typecasts

We register the function in hibernate to fix the issue

```
import org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributions;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributor;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

/**
 * Register the unaccent function for Postgres.
 */
public class UnaccentPsqlFunction implements FunctionContributor  {
    @Override
    public void contributeFunctions(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
        functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().registerNamed(
            "unaccent",
            functionContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getBasicTypeRegistry().resolve(StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
        );
    }
}
```

Then create a file `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributor` and add in it the reference to your class:

```
com.foo.UnaccentPsqlFunction
```